# Romanian text is written in gibberish by taking the original text and inserting after each vowel the letter p and the corresponding vowel

Tags: c#, arrays, string, visual-studio, compare

The code works well now. Fell free to use it if you need it.

**Problem:**

To write a console application that translates a text from gibberish into Romanian. The gibberish language is similar to Romanian. A Romanian text is written in gibberish by taking the original text and inserting after each vowel the letter p and the corresponding vowel.

Example:

**For input data:**

```
Apanapa aparepe meperepe.
```

**At the console it will show:**

```
Ana are mere
```

**Here is my code:**

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace FromGibberishUgly
{
    class Program
    {        
        private static string GibberishToRomanian(string text)
        {
            if (null == text)
                return "";

            const string vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text.Length);

            for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; ++i)
            {
                sb.Append(text[i]);                
                if (i < text.Length - 2 &&
                    vowels.Contains(text[i]) &&
                    text[i + 1] == 'p' &&
                    char.ToLower(text[i + 2]) == char.ToLower(text[i]))
                    i += 2;
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {               
            Console.WriteLine(GibberishToRomanian(Console.ReadLine()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are manually doing it instead of using a regular expression, you should loop the string, look for the `p` character, and if you find it look the previous and the following characters to see if they are vowels and they match. Something similar to `char[] vowels = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'}; if (line[i] == 'p' && vowels.Contains(line[i-1]) && line[i-1] == line[i+1])`.

Comment: @Cleptus I used your method, but I still get numbers as result.

Comment: Your input has no numbers in it, I dont understand what do you mean when you say "_I still get numbers as result_". You should explain what is problematic with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When having a *simple pattern* (`vowel + p + vowel` in your case) you can try using *regular expressions*:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

private static string GibberishToRomanian(string text) =>  
  Regex.Replace(text ?? "", @"([aeiou])p\1", "$1", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

**Demo:**

```
Console.Write(GibberishToRomanian("Apanapa aparepe meperepe"));
```

**Outcome:**

```
Ana are mere
```

**Pattern explained:**

```
([aeiou]) - capturing group #1 for any vowel
p         - letter 'p'
\1        - value captured by group #1
```

**Edit**: If you want to stick to loops, you can try put it like this:

```
private static string GibberishToRomanian(string text) {
  if (null == text)
    return "";

  const string vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text.Length);

  for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; ++i) {
    sb.Append(text[i]);

    // when facing vowel + p + vowel we jump over p + vowel 
    if (i < text.Length - 2 &&
        vowels.Contains(text[i]) &&
        text[i + 1] == 'p' &&
        char.ToLower(text[i + 2]) == char.ToLower(text[i]))
      i += 2;
  }

  return sb.ToString();
}
```

The program will be ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qdVvHp))

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace FromGibberishUgly {
  class Program {
    //TODO: or replace it with loop solution
    private static string GibberishToRomanian(string text) =>
      Regex.Replace(text ?? "", @"([aeiou])p\1", "$1", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    static void Main(string[] args) {
      Console.WriteLine(GibberishToRomanian(Console.ReadLine()));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That is actually a pretty nice use case of Regex

Comment: This is a bit too complicated for me, I do not understand the code and I do not know how to add it to my code and use it.

Comment: @Laurențiu Cozma: `Regex.Replace(text ?? "", @"([aeiou])p\1", "$1", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);` - 
we match `([aeiou])p\1` pattern (vowel + p + the same vowel) and replace it with the (first) vowel - `$1`. 
If we get `text == null`, we turn it into empty string - `text ?? ""`. I've edited the answer and provide a
typical loop solution and the usage

Comment: I used the loop solution, now I get this error "Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'StringBuilder' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

Comment: @Laurentiu Cozma: please, add `using System.Text;`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I edited the post, can you please look on the code? after I runt it, I get numbers as output instead of "Ana are mere"

Comment: @Laurențiu Cozma: please, *fiddle* - https://dotnetfiddle.net/qdVvHp